# Java-VSCode error:Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

first of all I read all the questions about the problem, but I could not find the answer.

The compiler sent me an error `"Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json."`but i don't know how i will solve this problem. Is there any know how i solve this?

Comment: Post your folder structure and the smallest code snippets, which is a huge help for reproducing your question and solving it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running "Clean Java Language Server Workspace" command helped me.

[image]

Comment: Did not help. I did not get any feedback from the cmd. Any others with other experience? What does the cmd? Is it like removing cache content from the jdk?

Comment: This is not helping if you don't tell how to make that bar appear...

Answer (score 3):

In project's folder create folder named ".vscode" with "settings.json" file inside including:

`{ "java.project.sourcePaths": [ "src" ] }`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please explain the code. I think that in `sourcepaths` you list the folders where `.java` files are. This is needed for VSCode to let the jdk know where the java files are that have to be compiled. If the java files are in the root, a `.` is probably correct. I do not think that you are right, because the question refers to `launch.json`, and you mention `settings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source path. Run the code and check for source path location. The code's source path was not like the previous main one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific with detailed examples. I only can guess from your words.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had this issue, despite cleaning the workspace, and ensuring that all the source paths were set correctly etc. Nothing I did would work, nor was there anything wrong with my project setup (I was using Gradle in this case).

The final act was to simply delete the whole project folder and re-clone it from my Git repo, and magically the error went away and I was able to run / debug my code. Very strange, but something somewhere was being cached that was causing this problem.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add the `launch.json` content