# Spring + Gradle does not found classpath in VSCode [Its not a duplicate, already checked the similar ones]

Tags: java, spring, gradle, visual-studio-code, classpath

First of all, yes, I tried clean java language server workspace and all other answers present here: [Java-VSCode error:Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302573/java-vscode-errorcannot-resolve-the-modulepaths-classpaths-automatically-pleas) , it doesn't work!

DON'T VOTE TO CLOSE BASED ON THIS QUESTION, PLEASE!

In trying to run a spring boot + gradle application, but it gives the following error:

> Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json.
>
> Source: Debugger for Java (Extension)

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Spring Boot-SigprojApplication<sigproj-backend>",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "mainClass": "com.sti.sigproj.SigprojApplication",
            "projectName": "sigproj-backend",
            "args": "",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my .classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/test" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="test"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.5.2"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.12.RELEASE"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.sti.sigproj.SigprojApplication'
        )
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.7.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.6.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-spring:2.3.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.5.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation('com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'snakeyaml' }
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.22'
    testImplementation 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test:5.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2'
}

group = 'com.sti.sigproj'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'sigproj-backend'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

test.testLogging {
    exceptionFormat 'full'
}

task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir 
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)
```

Here is the tree of directories and the place where SigprojApplication is found:

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── docker
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── sti
│   │           └── sigproj
│   │               ├── api
│   │               │   ├── controller
│   │               │   ├── exceptionhandler
│   │               │   └── generaldtos
│   │               ├── configs
│   │               │   └── security
│   │               ├── domain
│   │               │   ├── arquivos
│   │               │   ├── edital
│   │               │   ├── modalidade
│   │               │   ├── proposta
│   │               │   └── usuario
│   │               ├── SigprojApplication.java
│   │               └── support
│   │                   ├── date
│   │                   ├── faker
│   │                   ├── json
│   │                   ├── validations
│   │                   └── verificacoes
│   └── resources
│       └── db
│           └── migration
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── sti
                └── sigproj
                    ├── api
                    │   └── controllers
                    └── support
                        └── tests
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error message, please add the following configuration to your `launchjson` file:

```json
            "classPaths": [your_path_here],
            "modulePaths": [your_path_here]
```

Comment: Where exactly the classpath should point? Until the src, until the main... I posted the tree to find this answer also.

Comment: src, jre, and packages that may be used, etc.